# Using native ECMAScript modules in Babeljs config

Tags: javascript, babeljs, parceljs

I'm very, very confused about using babel config with native ECMAScript modules, and `"type": "module"` set in `package.json`. As far as I understand Babel docs ([here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files), under "Supported file extensions"), its should be possible. But if I try with config like this:

```
const config = () => {
  const presets = [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        bugfixes: true,
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        corejs: { version: "3.6", proposals: true },
      },
    ],
  ];
  const plugins = ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"];
  return { presets, plugins };
};
export default config;
```

I get `Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously`.

This is expected as the said docs states that "native ECMAScript modules are asynchronous". Alas, sprinkling the above config with `async` / `await` doesn't solve the problem. I'm running `babel` through `parcel` - is this a issue with `parcel`? Did I misunderstood the docs? I really appreciate if someone could clarify it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `package.json` says you are using **ES6 modules**, but your Babel config is using `module.exports` which is **CommonJS (not ES6 modules)**.

Rename `babel.config.js` to `babel.config.cjs`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem, and reading Babel site, I came to conclusion that whatever is using your babel config is not calling it asynchronously. In my case it was jest 26.
I got around the problem by changing the config to a json file - `babel.config.json`.
Other people have changed their config file to a commonjs file - `babel.config.cjs`, then you will need to change your config file to be commonjs, i.e. to use `module.exports = {rest of your config}`